# mongodb - "replication oplog window" possibly reduced due to profiling - when profiling disabled no change?

Tags: performance, replication, mongodb

## PROBLEM

I have a 3 member replica set (no sharding) running mongodb version 2.4.8.

Using MMS (Mongo Monitoring) I can see  that on 7th July 2014 at 12:00 my "replication oplog window" dropped from 2777.78 hours to 68 hours at its lowest point.

Looking back at my log of changes on this date I can see database profiling was enabled that morning.

"db.setProfilingLevel(0)" to disable profiling was executed an hour ago on all collections and on all members of the replica set (PRIMARY FIRST).

## QUESTION

An hour later my "replication oplog window" counter is still showing only 102 hours. Will this take time to increase again or should I be looking for another cause ?

Thank you
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i think i know the answer. The OPLOG collection is a capped collection. It overwrites over time. The profile level was set to 2 for a short period of time logging all operations. I guess it will take time to overwrite these operations on a capped collection again and as a result increase the op log window.

Would be interested in anyone elses take on this issue.

Thank you.